# Awk : recovery line with condition

Tags: awk, grep

I would like to create a file from another file by keeping only some lines that match with a pattern in a column.

A part of base file:

```
"1","rs543921925","ENSG00000187634","ENST00000616125","intron_variant"
"2","rs543921925","ENSG00000187634","ENST00000620200","intron_variant"
"3","rs543921925","ENSG00000187634","ENST00000617307","intron_variant"
"4","rs146327803","ENSG00000187634","ENST00000420190","missense_variant"
"5","rs146327803","ENSG00000187634","ENST00000437963","missense_variant"
"6","rs146327803","ENSG00000187634","ENST00000342066","missense_variant"
"7","rs146327803","ENSG00000187634","ENST00000618181","missense_variant"
```

File that I want:

```
"4","rs146327803","ENSG00000187634","ENST00000420190","missense_variant"
"5","rs146327803","ENSG00000187634","ENST00000437963","missense_variant"
"6","rs146327803","ENSG00000187634","ENST00000342066","missense_variant"
"7","rs146327803","ENSG00000187634","ENST00000618181","missense_variant"
```

I've tried:

```
awk -F'"' '$9 ~ /missense_variant/ { print $0 }'base_file.txt
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: change `'$9 ~ /missense_variant/` to `'$10 ~ /missense_variant/` , but before that in the orignial command try printing `$9` and see what it is. You will realize that it will never match `missense_variant`.

Comment: Right, because the empty string prior to the first " is $1

Comment: You can also use `grep '"missense_variant"$'`

Comment: And in your awk command, you can omit `{print $0}` -- see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info

Comment: Thank you, indeed, I was too quick and I didn't see which column was the right one. I had a hard time with the fact that each line begins with". Thank you for enlightening me on my carelessness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed `awk` script can do the trick but `grep` is easier and simpler.

Your script mistake is the field separator:

```
awk -F',' '$5 ~ /missense_variant/ { print }' base_file.txt
```

works well

but grep is simpler

```
grep "missense_variant\"$" input.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

I think sometimes it's better to use the actual file delimiters.

```
$ awk -F, '$NF=="\"missense_variant\"" base_file.txt
```

is probably what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

You could have easily figured this out for yourself:

```
$ awk -F'"' 'NR==1{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print NF, i, "<" $i ">"}' file
11 1 <>
11 2 <1>
11 3 <,>
11 4 <rs543921925>
11 5 <,>
11 6 <ENSG00000187634>
11 7 <,>
11 8 <ENST00000616125>
11 9 <,>
11 10 <intron_variant>
11 11 <>
```

Note what's in $9 vs $10.

Also, consider this for FS instead:

```
$ awk -F'^"|","|"$' 'NR==1{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print NF, i, "<" $i ">"}' file
7 1 <>
7 2 <1>
7 3 <rs543921925>
7 4 <ENSG00000187634>
7 5 <ENST00000616125>
7 6 <intron_variant>
7 7 <>
```

or:

```
$ awk -F'","' '{gsub(/^"|"$/,"")} NR==1{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print NF, i, "<" $i ">"}' file
5 1 <1>
5 2 <rs543921925>
5 3 <ENSG00000187634>
5 4 <ENST00000616125>
5 5 <intron_variant>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/missense_variant/{print $0}' file

"4","rs146327803","ENSG00000187634","ENST00000420190","missense_variant"
"5","rs146327803","ENSG00000187634","ENST00000437963","missense_variant"
"6","rs146327803","ENSG00000187634","ENST00000342066","missense_variant"
"7","rs146327803","ENSG00000187634","ENST00000618181","missense_variant"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your proposals, they work very well, I look at the one that is most appropriate to my problem thank you

Comment: please upvote valuable answers, and mark best answer.